# Median of Medians

Tags: statistics, data-analysis, median

Given a set **A** with median **A<sub>m</sub> = 10** and set **B** with median **B<sub>m</sub> = 20** is it true that the median of the combined set **C** is **$10 \le$ C<sub>m</sub>$\le 20$** ?

My first thought was that this wasn't true so I tried to find a counter example but I wasnt able to so I am assuming that it likely is true but I havent been able to find any theorem or other proof for this.

Ideally I would like to know if this is true for the general case not just 10,20 I just chose these numbers while trying to find a counter example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since  half the elements of $A$ exceed (or equal) $10$, and half of $B$ exceeds (or equals) $20$, it follows that at least half of $C$ exceeds (or equals) $10$.  Similarly on the other side.  Nothing special about $10,20$.

Comment: @lulu I understand your reasoning behind why this is true, logically it makes sense. But it just seems a little hand-wavy to me, how would you go about proving it. I attempted a proof by contradiction but couldnt get it to work

Comment: Suppose there are $2n$ elements of $A$ and $2m$ elements of $B$.  Then there are $n$ elements of $A$ which exceed (or equal) $10$ and $m$ elements of $B$ that exceed (or equal) $20$. of course the latter implies that there are at least $m$ elements of $B$ which exceed (or equal) $10$.  Combining those we see that there are at least $m+n$ elements of $C$ which exceed or equal $10$, so the median of $C$ is at least $10$.  The odd case is similar, if there are $2n+1$ elements of $A$ then there are at least $n+1$ elements in $A$ which exceed or equal $10$.

Comment: Ah yes ok this makes sense. If you want to write this up as an answer id be glad to accept it. If not thanks for the help, its much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. I'll repost it as a solution...the site gets unhappy if questions go unanswered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose there are $2n$ elements of $A$ and $2m$ elements of $B$. Then there are $n$ elements of $A$ which exceed (or equal) $10$ and $m$ elements of $B$ that exceed (or equal) $20$. of course the latter implies that there are at least $m$ elements of $B$ which exceed (or equal) $10$. Combining those we see that there are at least $n+m$ elements of $C$ which exceed or equal $10$, so the median of $C$ is at least $10$. The odd case is similar: if there are $2n+1$ elements of $A$ then there are at least $n+1$ elements in $A$ which exceed or equal  $10$, and so on.